# How to click the next HTMLInputImage with the same name in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I've been stuck on a project now for some days now and it' killing me. I have been getting  lots of help from this place and for that Im thankful!! Now, to the problem:

What I want my program to do when I press my "collect button" is to automatically click on every button with the name "icon_go.GIF" on the page, and after that collect some information from that page. The problem I have right now is that when my program is pressing the first button, there are 10, it loads the page and collects the first piece of information. BUT then that first button is "first" again so it gets clicked on again. This countinues 10 times, because there are 10 inputImages...

How can I make my code to understand to click the next "icon_go.GIF" button and not the one from the last time?

Here is the code I've got now:

```
private void btnCollect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  SHDocVw.ShellWindows AllBrowsers = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();

  foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ieInst in AllBrowsers)
  {

     mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 htmlDoc = ieInst.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;

     foreach (mshtml.IHTMLElement element in htmlDoc.all)
     {

         var input = element as mshtml.IHTMLInputImage;

         if (input != null && Path.GetFileName(input.src).Equals("icon_go.GIF", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
         {

             ((mshtml.IHTMLElement)input).click(); // Click the icon_go.GIF button

             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // Wait 1 sec to load new page

             html = htmlDoc.body.outerHTML;

             /*
             Collecting info here
             */
          }
     }
 }
```

Here is some of the html code:

```
<TD align=center><INPUT title="View Detail Statistics" style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: 14px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 14px" src="../App_Themes/Company/Images/icon_go.GIF" type=image name=process1></TD></TR>
<TD align=center><INPUT title="View Detail Statistics" style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: 14px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 14px" src="../App_Themes/Company/Images/icon_go.GIF" type=image name=process2></TD></TR>
```

I Hope you guys understand what I'm trying to say here.. 
Thanks!!

Comment: why do you have to click each button? every time you click on web forms, you are causing a postback, refreshing the page. Why not move the logic to a separate method, and call that method once for each button? this way you only have one click, collect a list of buttons, and for each button, call new method.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow.. You mean if I take whats in my if statement and make a method of it? Wont it be the same thing? Can you show what you mean in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question! Followed mmeasors advice and made a list of all the inputs!